# Providing struct constructor from library

Tags: racket

I'm currently working on extending [racklog](https://github.com/MLavrentyev/racklog), which is a library I installed by running `raco pkg install` in the repo directory.

I'm trying to provide a new function, namely a struct constructor. Currently, I'm defining the struct as follows in `racklog.rkt`. I then provide it from that file.

```lisp
; racklog.rkt
(struct my-struct (value))
(provide my-struct)
```

The main file of the library just provides everything from this file:

```lisp
; main.rkt
(require "racklog.rkt")
(provide (all-from-out "racklog.rkt"))
```

However, when I try to use the provided constructor (which should be named `my-struct`) in a file requiring this module, it says that the id isn't found. In particular, I'm trying:

```lisp
; test.rkt
(require racklog)
my-struct
```

This also happens even with non-struct things such as defined variables, functions, etc. All the other provided forms seem to be working fine. What's the way I can fix this so I can use the provided constructor? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate stale compiled file issue. Try `raco setup --pkgs racklog` to compile `racklog` and run your program again. It should now work. Alternatively, you can manually delete the `compiled` directories.